# Data loading issue in jupyter lab

Tags: python, image, image-processing, conv-neural-network, jupyter-lab

When I give path of data reading it give error of not picking parts of data even though I have given the right path but still can't seem to work with it.

I have a screen shot to show the error that i am getting

[image: error that is occuring]

```py
class_names=['mountain','street','glacier','buildings','sea','forest']
class_names_label={class_name: i for i,class_name  in enumerate(class_names)}
nb_classes=len(class_names)
print(class_names_label)
print(nb_classes)
IMAGE_SIZE=(150,150)

#loading data
def load_data():
    DIRECTORY=r"C:\3 symester\4 sym\AI project\image classification"
    CATEGORY=["seg_train","seg_test"]

    output=[]

    for category in CATEGORY:
        path=os.path.join(DIRECTORY,category)
        print(path)
        images=[]
        labels=[]

        print("Loading {}".format(category))

        for folder in os.listdir(path):
            label=class_names_label[folder]

                #iterate througheach image in our folder
                for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,folder)):
                    #get path name of img
                    img_path=os.path.join(os.path.join(path,folder),file)
                    
                    #open and resize the image
                    image=cv2.imread(img_path)
                    image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    image=cv2.resize(image,IMAGE_SIZE)
                    
                    #Append the image and its corresponding label to the output
                    image.append(image)
                    labels.append(label)
                    images=np.array(images,dtype='float32')
                    labels=np.array(labels,dtype='int32')

                    output.append((images,labels))
    return output
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but the reason why you're getting an error is because the dictionary `class_names_label` **does not** have the key `seg_train`. Your dictionary is initialized with these values `class_names=['mountain','street','glacier','buildings','sea','forest']`. Which don't include `seg_train`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)